# php script for multiple selects and an insert running much slower than it was

Tags: php, mysql, sql, db2

I have a working script that selects from a database, stores parameters for a 2nd select query and then inserts some of those selected values, along with mild aggregations, into a final DB table.

This script works perfectly fine and returns/inserts the data expected but it's taking FOREVER to run.

In 20 minutes it's done about 300 records.

I'm a just totally missing something here that would cause it to run so slowly?

```
$selectPlacements = "
    SELECT DISTINCT
        sku_id, s.frame as frame, sg.group_code as group_code, sg.name as group_name, s.cover1 as cover, s.color1 as color, dealer_id
    FROM placements p
    inner join skus s 
    on p.sku_id = s.id
    inner join sku_groups sg 
    on sg.id = s.sku_group_id
    where p.expire_date > curdate()
    ;
";

try {
    $placementCheck = $MysqlConn->prepare($selectPlacements);
    $detailRslt = $placementCheck->execute();

     while ($placementRow = $placementCheck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        print_r($placementRow); //This prints the array I need

        $salesValues = [
        ":dealer_id" => $placementRow["dealer_id"],
        ":frame" => $placementRow["frame"],
        ":cover" => $placementRow["cover"],
        ":color" => $placementRow["color"],
        "group_code" => $placementRow["group_code"],
        "group_name" => $placementRow["group_name"],
        ];



        $checkSales = "
            SELECT
                count(*) as sales_180,
                180/count(*) as velocity,
                CAST(:group_code AS CHAR(10)),
                CAST(:group_name AS CHAR(10)),
                cr.xslsno as salesNum,
                cr.slsupr as VP
            FROM group g
                inner join custRecords cr
                    on g.cstnoc = cr.xcstno
            WHERE g.cstnoc = :dealer_id
                AND g.framec = :frame
                AND g.covr1c = :cover
                AND g.colr1c = :color
                AND date(substr(g.extd1d,1,4)||'-'||substr(g.EXTD1d,5,2)||'-'||substr(g.EXTD1d,7,2) ) between current_Date - 180 DAY AND current_Date
            GROUP BY cr.xslsno, cr.slsupr
        ";

        try{    
            $salesCheck = $DB2conn->prepare($checkSales);
            $salesResult = $salesCheck->execute($salesValues);

            $insertSales = "

                INSERT INTO testmetrics (dealer, frame, cover, color, groupnum, groupname, last180days_sales, velocity, repnumber, vpnumber )
                VALUES (
                    :dealer_id, 
                    :frame,
                    :cover,
                    :color,
                    :group_code,
                    :group_name,
                    :SALES_180,
                    :VELOCITY,
                    :SALESNUM,
                    :VP
                )
            ";

            $velocityInsertPrep = $DB2conn->prepare($insertSales);

            while ($salesRow = $salesCheck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                $salesValues[":SALES_180"] = $salesRow["SALES_180"];
                $salesValues[":VELOCITY"] = $salesRow["VELOCITY"];
                $salesValues[":SALESNUM"] = $salesRow["SALESNUM"];
                $salesValues[":VP"] = $salesRow["VP"];


                print_r($salesValues);
                try{

                    $velocityExecution = $velocityInsertPrep->execute($salesValues);

                }catch(PDOException $ex){

                    echo "INSERT_FAILED: " .$ex->getMessage();

                }


             }

        }catch(PDOException $ex) {
            echo "QUERY TWO FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage(); 
        }
    }

}catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo "QUERY ONE FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. Additionally, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Comment: Which part is slow? Have you tried monitoring your databases? For Db2, download IBM Data Server Manager, or try `dsmtop`.

Comment: In addition to what @Strawberry said, try to determine which query is slow: the one for MySQL, or the one for DB2. Run just the one for MySQL, time it, and EXPLAIN (or ANALYZE) ; if you are no satisfied, repeat for db2. You may discover that all you need is to create indexes on your MySQL tables, since that is where you are selecting from.

Comment: I'll try that @fotang. The mysql query returns about 40000 rows in under 2 seconds. The next select is on db2 based on those original results though

Comment: The last condition of the where-clause (starting with `date(substr(g.extd1d,1,4)...`) could be slowing down things. After adding indexes for color, frame and cover, you may want to optimise the date concatenation, perhaps by storing its different components as generated columns.

Comment: `extd1d` should be of `DATE` data-type to avoid the need to convert it to a date on the fly. You could aslo consider a `SELECT from NEW_TABLE(INSERT...)` to merge the two Db2 statements into one statement.

Comment: I optimized dates by joining on a table that has all date formats, so that helped some. The real slowdown seems to come from my custRecords JOIN though. Trying to figure that out. @fotang so if I make a unique index on my mysql table in the original select and I make a unique index on my db2 where I'm inserting, would that be sufficient?

Comment: @TomN. The index should be on the table from which you are selecting. Selecting from MySQL was fast,as you said. Now to db2: Add an index on table custRecords, column xcstno. (`CREATE INDEX idx_xcstno ON custRecords(xcstno)`).